# Does Swift 2 provide native sockets? (Not counting stuff from Cocoa etc.)

Tags: swift, sockets, native

I recently went through the Swift docs and decided to use it in a project just for the heck of it. It's not iOS/OSX related and I'm using the recently released Ubuntu port of Swift 2.2.

Basically, I have a TCP server running on an embedded system written in C. I was going to write a Swift client to connect to it, but it appears Swift does not have any 'native' implementation of sockets. Most of what I found online uses NSStreams which are a part of the Cocoa framework (AFAIK that's independent of Swift and only available on iOS and OSX based systems).

For example, in Ruby you can simply `require 'socket'` and `TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)` as its in the standard library.

I realize that I could write my own C code and access that via Swift but I'd really prefer a native solution if one exists.

Comment: Have a look at this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71861/pure-swift-solution-for-socket-programming

Comment: Saw this earlier while googling. Unfortunately, it makes use of constructs only available on Darwin.

Comment: Maybe this will help you then, on the left hand side under `Source Samples` check out `server.swift` http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dWdevcenter-_-swift-_-lp#/repl

Comment: Most of the basic Unix(ish) APIs that come from the Darwin module on Apple platforms have equivalents in the Glibc module on Linux. It's not very "Swifty", but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Only BSD socket API are provided and you can call these API in Swift to do socket programming.

I highly recommend you to use a socket framework to start with.

[SwiftDSSocket](https://github.com/csujedihy/SwiftDSSocket) is a framework written in pure Swift and I actively maintain this framework.